# PyGame Moniter dimming during game

Tags: python, pygame, monitor

I am creating a simple side-scrolling space game for a presentation I will be giving at my school. I decided i should learn how to use joystick inputs as a challenge. It's really cool and almost done, but i noticed that while I'm playing, if I don't move the mouse every now and then, the monitor dims and looks like it's about to go into power save. Is there any way I can avoid this?

Comment: Just to clairify, this IS your PC dimming the display correct? Not Pygame itself?

Comment: Yes, the monitor is acting as if I just let it sit there with no input, even though I'm using the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pygame
x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
pygame.mouse.set_pos([x+1,y+1])
pygame.mouse.set_pos([x,y])
```

It's not the neatest solution, but this will simulate a mouse movement.
There's probably API's you can call or use of Pythons [signal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) library.
But depending on your platform the solution might vary quite a lot.

Or if you need to move the cursor when the window is not active?

```
import win32api, win32con
def move(x,y,press=False):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    if press:
        click(x,y)
def click(x,y):
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
move(10,10,True)
```

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine in hand, but i'd assume you can do `win32api.GetCursorPos()` and just make the cursor blip to `(x,y)` and then back to the original position again.

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump)

I am going to guess that you getting joystick inputs from the `pygame.joystick` and not from `pygame.event`.
If so, you maybe able to stop the computer from beginning to sleep by calling [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump).

This should be called if no other `pygame.event` function is called, so background these can happen, and the system does not mistake the processed for non-responsive. 
[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) would also be a working solution, if you also wanted events.

I tested this on OSX (10.13.3), but I know that `pump()` acts differently on different operating systems, so your results may vary (please comment).

It is also worth noting that the `pygame.mouse.set_pos()` did not work for me as it seems to do nothing on MacOS at the moment (pygame: 1.9.4.dev0).